# Como recuperar um token de acesso com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-security

Tenho uma api e estou consumindo ela no frontend.
minha api na url /login me gera um token de acesso.
Preciso dentro do meu login.js fazer uma requisição POST que retorne o token.
Observação,  o token retornado não é um json, quando faço um teste no insonia para ver se a api está devolvendo o token ele apenas me retorna o token como um texto enorme, e preciso via JavaScript este retorno e salvar  em uma variável.

```
btnEntrar.onclick = async e  =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    if (email.value == '' || senha.value == '') {
      return
    }
    let paylog = {"email": email.value, "senha":senha.value}
  
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(paylog),
    });
    const data = await JSON.stringify(response)
    console.log(response)
```

O retorno é um erro falando que não é um json válido.

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'p',
> "persidh.cr"... is not valid JSON VM43:1

Answer (score -1):

Vamos lá.
Você não precisaria do JSON.stringfy.

Isso somente irá transformar em um texto transformado DE json para string.
Como você recebe já uma string, ele te retorna dizendo que tem um token inválido (não reconhece como json pra poder transformar)
Tente deixar na penultima linha somente data = response.
e consolar isso

Comment: O pessoal não responde, mas so avalia negativo uma resposta que ajudaria a pessoa. Stackoverflow Brasil ta virando piada com a comunidade que se acha Deus